# Why doesn't my SVG map with paths appear on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, svg

I have a website that uses an SVG containing several paths. It appears and works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but not in Safari on iOS. Here is an extract of my SVG file (which is very long at 659 lines):

```html
<svg id="retailer-map"
   viewBox="0 0 590 650"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
   id="svg2"
   >
  <defs
     id="defs4">
  </defs>
  <path data-num="2B"
     d="M 562.13712,441.70296 L 559.29258,443.60941 L 559.68597,445.48559 L 561.19903,447.39204 L 559.50441,448.69326 L 560.26093,450.20631 L 559.11102,451.5378 L 559.11102,453.23242 L 561.01746,454.95729 L 561.01746,457.59 L 559.86754,460.04115 L 558.56632,460.61611 L 557.05327,458.5281 L 554.39029,458.73992 L 553.81534,458.34653 L 551.54576,458.34653 L 549.48801,460.25297 L 548.70122,463.46064 L 543.79893,464.39873 L 540.01631,467.6064 L 539.25978,469.69441 L 537.3836,469.51285 L 536.41524,468.36293 L 535.87055,471.60086 L 534.53906,472.14556 L 534.14567,475.17166 L 534.72063,476.50315 L 532.63262,478.0162 L 532.05766,479.52925 L 534.17593,479.92264 L 534.53906,480.95152 L 538.29143,480.95152 L 539.3203,481.61726 L 542.07406,481.10282 L 543.25424,481.79883 L 542.7398,482.64613 L 544.61598,485.21832 L 548.21704,485.21832 L 549.09461,487.79051 L 551.63654,487.79051 L 551.48524,489.33382 L 553.54299,491.90601 L 554.57186,492.42045 L 555.93361,493.26776 L 555.93361,496.53595 L 556.96248,497.38326 L 559.02023,497.38326 L 559.53467,498.23056 L 559.86754,502.8605 L 561.07798,503.70781 L 560.56354,504.40381 L 560.89642,507.12731 L 564.83035,506.976 L 568.1288,504.79721 L 568.00776,499.19892 L 572.54691,492.78358 L 572.54691,482.19222 L 570.67073,478.59116 L 570.09577,467.24327 L 568.76428,465.15526 L 566.31314,463.27908 L 565.91975,456.25852 L 567.06967,453.05085 L 565.55661,447.93674 L 564.61852,443.79097 L 563.83174,442.64106 L 562.13712,441.70296 z "
     
     class="land departement corse departement2b"
     inkscape:label="Haute-Corse"><title>Haute-Corse (2B)</title></path>
  <path data-num="82"
     d="M 266.55906,372.63392 L 265.22758,376.96124 L 267.31559,379.23082 L 266.3775,382.83188 L 265.22758,384.16337 L 266.01436,386.43295 L 262.4133,387.18947 L 259.56877,387.946 L 260.32529,390.57871 L 258.90302,391.00236 L 259.75033,391.78915 L 262.50409,391.78915 L 263.86583,391.12341 L 265.07627,391.78915 L 262.83696,392.81802 L 262.83696,394.5429 L 260.77921,396.08621 L 260.77921,398.29527 L 264.56184,398.47684 L 265.74202,399.68728 L 265.74202,402.0779 L 267.13402,403.43964 L 265.92358,405.31583 L 266.43802,406.3447 L 268.82864,405.31583 L 273.79145,405.31583 L 275.18346,404.46852 L 276.87807,404.46852 L 278.75426,406.70784 L 283.05132,405.49739 L 284.2315,403.62121 L 282.53689,402.74364 L 283.71707,402.25946 L 284.0802,400.53459 L 285.95638,400.71615 L 286.98526,401.89633 L 287.83257,400.53459 L 290.58632,399.50571 L 291.82702,400.08067 L 292.79538,398.47684 L 291.10076,396.60065 L 294.33869,396.60065 L 295.36756,394.72447 L 297.60688,392.66672 L 295.36756,392.66672 L 296.06357,389.76166 L 301.87368,389.06566 L 304.113,387.70391 L 306.83649,386.67503 L 307.71406,385.79746 L 306.65493,383.07397 L 308.19824,379.98735 L 305.47475,379.80578 L 305.14187,375.53898 L 301.02638,377.41516 L 298.27262,376.74942 L 296.578,378.80717 L 293.67295,378.44403 L 293.15851,381.86353 L 291.7665,381.86353 L 290.91919,379.98735 L 290.40475,379.14004 L 288.86144,379.29134 L 285.95638,382.37797 L 282.35532,382.22666 L 281.84088,379.98735 L 281.84088,378.29273 L 281.50801,377.9296 L 280.29757,379.29134 L 278.75426,379.29134 L 277.05964,377.41516 L 275.51633,377.41516 L 274.48745,375.35741 L 275.8492,373.8141 L 275.69789,372.81548 L 273.27701,372.90627 L 273.57962,373.57201 L 269.4036,374.32853 L 266.55906,372.63392 z "
     inkscape:label="Tarn-et-Garonne"
     class="land departement midi departement82"><title>Tarn-et-Garonne (82)</title></path>
[..]
</svg>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: This was generated with inkscape but lacks the inkspace namespace. It looks something like `xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"` Try adding it or remove the `inkscape:label` attribute of the paths

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I found the solution.

iOS block the display of an svg if the parent of the svg has the CSS property display configure to flex.

So I change my div (that is the parent of the svg) CSS property display to block and it works.